# Create new Series from existing Series and map values

Tags: rust, rust-polars

My use case: I have a column with wild time stamps (strings) and I want to parse them into a timestamp type.

[The docs](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html) mention `ChunkedArray` to be the typed container for my strings.

However, I cannot complete the picture.

```rust
fn with_timestamps(mut df: DataFrame) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {
    let column = df.column("myTime")?.clone(); // clone, just for a good measure ...

    let ca = column.utf8()?; // ChunkedArray

    // I think I want something like this:
    let new_time = Series::new("newTime", ca.into_iter().map(|v: &str| 42).collect());

    // 42 is not a timestamp,
    // but maybe I can work on that from an integer

    df.with_column(new_time);
    df
}
```

Apart from that I need to find out whether `.with_column()` acts in place, I have trouble to identify from the docs what am I supposed to iterate over. Is is the `Series`, the `ChunkedArray` and do I construct the new `Series` from a new `ChunkedArray` or from an iterator I can `collect()` or whatever.

**Edit**

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276752/how-to-use-date-in-polars-in-rust) as well, and with a little bit of fighting I came up with this example which is working in my case:

```rust
let df = df!("Fruit" => &["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"],
                            "Color" => &["Red", "Yellow", "Green"],
                            "Date" => &["02/21/2022 07:51:00 AM", "2/21/2022 07:51:00 AM", "2/21/2022 07:51:00 AM"])?;
let options = StrpTimeOptions {
    fmt: Some("%-m/%-d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p".into()),
    date_dtype: polars::datatypes::DataType::Datetime(TimeUnit::Milliseconds, None),
    exact: true,
    ..Default::default()
};

let foo = df
    .clone()
    .lazy()
    .with_columns([
       col("Date")
       .str()
       .strptime(options)
       .alias("parsed date")
     ])
    .collect();
```

Please note the `.lazy()`. Without it, the `Expr` (`col("Foo").alias("bar"`) seems not directly usable (is not a `Series`, whereas the lazy API expects only an expression), and my understanding of the Rust compiler message is not sufficient at the moment to figure out why and what would be the idiomatic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think this may be what you want:

```
let parsed_time: Series = df
    .column("myTime")?
    .clone()
    .utf8()?
    .into_iter()
    .map(| v: Option<&str> | your_parse_fn(v) )
    .collect();

df.with_column(parsed_time)
df
```

If I am correct---------
THIS WILL OVERWRITE YOUR DATA!

comment and let me know

Comment: What is wrong in your (and my) example is the `&str` which should be `Option<&str>`, but apart from that, your example seems to work - thank you for that!

Comment: Fixed it for anyone in the future